# Parse/deconstruct SQL with VBA-Access

Tags: sql, parsing, ms-access, teradata

Does anyone know of a way to deconstruct a SQL statement (take a select SQL statement, extract columns from each SELECT, tables from each FOR and each JOIN, and filtering criteria from each WHERE. I can then put this data into a BOM table to create a "map" of the query), including subqueries, using VBA? I have a project to map Teradata views into a Access DB. I'd like to have an automated method to do this.

Comment: Are you trying to parse the SQL?

Comment: I want to take a select SQL statement, extract columns from each SELECT, tables from each FOR and each JOIN, and filtering criteria from each WHERE. I can then put this data into a BOM table to create a "map" of the query.

Comment: If you save a SELECT statement as an Access QueryDef, you can identify the output fields by looking through the QueryDef.Fields collection.  Unfortunately, that is only one of the items you want.  I don't know how to get the others.

Comment: The QueryDef object lacks a Fields collection, but if you open it as a recordset, the Fields collection gets you both the list of Fields, and each Field has a SourceTable property. This would only work on SELECT statements, though. This all seems a pretty complicated task. On the other hand, I'd think a generic SQL parser would be a pretty common task and it might that they exist in other languages and the logic could be ported to VBA.

Comment: `CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryMinutesPerClient").Fields.Count` returns 2.  `CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryMinutesPerClient").SQL` returns `SELECT Time_Sub.CLIENT_ID, Sum(Time_Sub.MINUTES) AS SumOfMINUTES
FROM Time_Sub
GROUP BY Time_Sub.CLIENT_ID;`  That was from Access 2003.

Comment: You are correct, Hans -- I have no idea what I was doing wrong. The same properties I described for a recordset are avaliable. This means you can at least figure out the fields and the source tables for all types of queries, not just SELECTs.

Answer (score 1):

You want access to arbitrary substructures of a SQL query (incuding sub SELECTs)?  What you need is a full parser for the SQL dialect of interest.

SQL is a pretty large and complicated language.  It is possible to hand-code a recursive descent parser to do this, but that's quite a lot of work.  You'd be likely better off with a parser generator and an SQL BNF to feed it.

But the fact that you want to do this in VBA hints that you are unlikely to find such a parser generator.  You may have to call a parser generator coded in another langauge (e.g., C#) if you want to have a reasonable chance of doing this with modest effort, and go find a preexisting SQL parser.